# Total Unique Searches equivalent in GA4

Tags: google-analytics

In UA we used to run stats on Site Search, and specifically we reported on the Total Unique Searches from the 'search terms' report under the Behaviour group of reports.

In GA4 there doesn’t seem to be a comparable metric. We are using the view_search_results event to report on how the site is being searched.  However the event count for this is much higher than the Total Unique Searches we used to report on.

It seems that the Event Count is actually the same as Results Page Views/Search count from the Site Search report in UA.

Is there a way to get the equivalent to UA Total Unique Searches in GA4, which doesn't count search terms that are duplicated in the same session?

I have read about a unique_search_term which is a  parameter of view_search_results. Apparenlty it returns the value 1 if the search term is unique in the session.

I have added unique_search_term as a custom definition, but it is coming into the Explore reports as (not set)